# Regular expression for removing whitespaces in code

Tags: regex, sublimetext, matching

If I had a code like this:

```
var     foo       = 5;
if  (  bar > 2) {  bar    += foo;}
```

It should turn into this:

```
var foo=5;
if(bar>2){bar+=foo;}
```

It removes spaces that has no letters in between and avoids keyword/variable errors.
If you have two words the space between it will be one whitespace.

`\s+(?=[^A-z])` is the closest I could find, but doesn't match all of the spaces.

Comment: Why would it not turn into `varfoo=5;` as well?

Comment: `varfoo` will result a compile error.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that. I'm asking how you expect your regex to know that, and not make that replacement. IOW, a regex is the wrong solution; you need a code formatter that can parse the language and understand the grammar and that is aware of they syntax and keywords. A regex isn't appropriate. I don't understand why everyone's first thought is *I know! Let's make it more of a problem by trying to force a regex into it!*

Comment: I don't know what language you used, look like Javascript. Regardless, code parsing is very complex. You are better of with a linter (a.k.a. code beautifier) for your specific language

Comment: And if you have code like `if ("bar > 2" == x) {}` should it turn into `if ("bar>2"==x) {}` ?

Comment: Yes, it should. But it might be more difficult if you're planning to check if you're inside a string.

Comment: I know there is code compressors online but I wanted a regex for Sublime Text that's quick to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
let re = /(?!\b\s*\w)\s*/gm;
```

Edit: In your code, just replace the `let` and `const` with `var` for ES5.

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/qN4fH6/1)

```js
let str = `var     foo       = 5;
if  (  bar > 2) {  bar    += foo;}`;

const re = /(?!\b\s*\w)\s*/gm;

str = str.replace(re, '');

document.body.textContent = str;
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out Rails `squish` method:

http://apidock.com/rails/String/squish

Answer (score 0):

`replace(/?=[\w][^\n\t]+/," ")` would replace all the multiple space's with single spaces so that owuld get you half way there. Beyond that if you really wanted things particular you could remove all the white space and add the spaces back in after all the key words that require spaces... I wouldn't recommend that though as it would break code with variable names containing keywords.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
REST=cat # Whatever the rest of your pipeline is...

( cat <<EOF
var     foo       = 5;
if  (  bar > 2) {  bar    += foo;}
EOF
)\
| tr -s '\t ' " " \
| sed \
    -e 's/\([[:punct:]]\) /\1/g' \
    -e 's/ \([[:punct:]]\)/\1/g' \
| $REST
```

Output is:

```
$ sh test.sh
var foo=5;
if(bar>2){bar+=foo;}
```